# Could not connect to development server. Error while running

Tags: ios, macos, react-native, react-native-ios, hybrid-mobile-app

I have tried to restart the server with `npm start`, `npx react-native run-ios`, `npx react-native start`. Those commands don't work for me. Help me out to run this project its a project created with `npx react native init projectName`.

warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.

[The error shown on the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn47C.png)

Answer (score 1):

Run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` in your terminal then reload in the terminal after running `yarn start` or `npm start`, then reload. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I think that your answer is for the android emulator, but my problem is with the ios simulator.Thanks for your reply

Comment: @YethinDias did you find a solution for ios simulator? if so could you please post here?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and spent hours working on it. I figured out that METRO which is run using this command: *npm start* or this one *npx react-native start* couldn't find its way to my mobile app.

one of the solutions that I wasn't totally pleased of was this: [a solution that works but has flows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW1UM.png)

but that workaround wasn't perfect because I had to re-run the command every single time I make a change. So after further researches I found out that the port 8081 is used by an another application that METRO is sending information to ( this is only my guess ). so:

1. I run the following:

   `netstat -aon | findstr 8081 // to get the PID of the application that is running on 8081 port`
2. I opened task manager ( `CRTL + ALT + del` ) under the *service* section I looked up any
   application which uses the PID that matches the one given by the command I ran and I have
   forced stopping it.
3. retried `npx react-native start` and `npx react-native run-android` on my project

and the magic happened. It auto refreshes with every change, I wish it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the docs:

Method 2: Connect via Wi-Fi

You can also connect to the development server over Wi-Fi. You'll
first need to install the app on your device using a USB cable, but
once that has been done you can debug wirelessly by following these
instructions. You'll need your development machine's current IP
address before proceeding.

Open a terminal and type /sbin/ifconfig to find your machine's IP address.

1. Make sure your laptop and your phone are on the same Wi-Fi network.
2. Open your React Native app on your device.
3. You'll see a red screen with an error. This is OK. The following
   steps will fix that.
4. Open the in-app Developer menu.
5. Go to Dev Settings → Debug server host for device.
6. Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev
   server (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081).
7. Go back to the Developer menu and select Reload JS